# What is the difference between jiva and atman

Tags: atma, jiva, jivatman

Im pretty confused about this topic. I have read many answers to it on the web and every one is different. One says that they are the same, other say that the jiva is the mind and body while atma is the original self, and the jivatman is combination of these two. Could someone clear this up for me?

Comment: Your idea of yourself is jiva. The one who lives that is Jiva. Now your idea of yourself comes from your mind. So people sometimes say that Jiva is mind. Atman is completely different thing. Actually its not a thing. It is beyond existance and non-existance. Just forget about Atman. Whoever tells you anything about Atman, don't trust them because Atman can't be talked about.